# Sorting an array by a specific key

Tags: php, sorting

In my code below I would like to sort the array `$v` by its key `title`, which has only numeric values.

```
foreach ($archive_years as $key => $value) {
    $id = str_replace(' ', '', $key);
    echo '
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#archiv_'. $id .'"><h3>'. $key .' </h3></button>
        <div id="archiv_'. $id .'" class="collapse">
            <ul>
    ';
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        ksort($v);
        var_dump($v);
        if (get_page($v['id'])->post_content) {
            echo '<li><h4><a href="'. $v["permalink"] .'">'. $v["title"] .' - '. $v["titel"] .'</a></h4></li>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<li><h4>'. $v["title"] .' - '. $v["titel"] .'</h4></li>';
        }

    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

I have tried using `ksort($v);` but that seems not to work in this case.

This is what `echo "<pre/>";print_r($v);` returns:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is ther in `$v`? show us for one by doing `echo "<pre/>";print_r($v);`

Comment: @Anant I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `usort`, if you need your own compare function.

I.e. you could try something like this:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    // should work, as title is numeric. to change the direction
    // just change $a and $b
    return $a['title'] - $b['title'];
});
```

Comment: I have tested your code but for some reason it is not working for me. The array still can't get sorted by title.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a logical comparison sign instead of the minus? (`<` or `>`)

Comment: Thank you, that actually works! I just had to use it for the array `$value` instead of `$v`.

Comment: No, you dont need < or >. The compare function expects a value smaller, greater or equal to zero. Eo just doing the math is sufficient.